# DrawerLayout with Google Maps

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having an issue with Google's DrawerLayout when it is placed in an activity with a map fragment. I have not tried with a MapView, however I fear the problem would remain the same.

I am using google's DrawerLayout from the support library (v13), and placing a map within it.

The problem I have is better explained through images... On 2.2-2.3 (fine on 4.0+) the drawer doesn't appear if it's over wherever the google map fragment is drawn. The remainder of the view, along with widgets on the view get shaded properly, but not the map.

Here is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4">
        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:scrollingCache="false"
                map:cameraTargetLat="39.828325"
                map:cameraTargetLng="-98.579728"
                map:cameraZoom="2"
                map:cameraTilt="0"
                map:cameraBearing="0"/>
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_fragmentHolder"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <include
        layout="@layout/menu_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is what is seen on 2.x devices, the screenshot is taken within the Android debug monitor, and the square should be one of my DrawerLayout's buttons

[image: Android 2.x]

This is how it should look:

[image: Android 4.x]

I have fears that this is caused by the fact that the Gmaps object is drawn on a FrameLayout, but I don't really know.

Anybody run into this issue or have ideas on how to resolve? Thanks.

Comment: I am getting the problem as well. Worse is that I experience it on a phone running 4.0.3. No issues on devices running Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into this issue and I attempted this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16231935/267559.  It worked for me.  Please give it a try.

Comment: BTW, a transparent FrameLayout works too and apparently is lighter in weight than View.  Give that a try.