# android : SlidingDrawer, RelativeLayout and GoogleMap

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have a google map with a sliding drawer. The widget is over the google map but I would like put my google maps above the content from sliding drawer (not above the sliding drawer). I can't place a property like above or below on `@+id/content` because the `LinearLayout` is not a child of `RelativeLayout`.

So my question : Is it possible ?

The only way I find is to put a `android:layout_marginBottom` on the map but is not very clean

It's more explicit with the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#40000000"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_refresh_map"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<com.ui.custom.WrappingSlidingDrawer
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ecab"
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:background="#00000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    [...]
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    [...]
    </LinearLayout>
</com.ui.custom.WrappingSlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[SlidingDrawer over GoogleMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432961/slidingdrawer-over-googlemap/16231935#16231935)

Didn't quite know if it helps or not i tryed and got two parts instead of a kind of overlay but check it out