# Android MapView overlaps DrawerLayout

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, drawerlayout

I have simple layout structure:

```
DrawerLayout
\-- FrameLayout // @+id/fragment_container
\-- ListView    // @+id/drawer_list
```

By clicking of any drawer item I'm inserting/replacing fragment via `FragmentTransaction.replace()` into `R.id.fragment_container` with corresponding Fragment instance. One of those Fragments contains `MapView`.

And it has rendering problems on different devices, but at the same time DDMS shows me right screenshot.

**EDITED**

Issue appears on such devices:

- **Huawei U9508**, Android 4.0.4 (API 15)
- **HTC Desire A9191**, Android 2.3.5 (API 10)

There is `no issue` on such devices:

- **Samsung Galaxy S2** with CyanogenMod Android 4.2.2 (API 17)
- **LG Google Nexus 4** Android 4.3 (API 18)

Could anybody help me to understand and fix this problem?

See images:

**Huawei U9508**, Android 4.0.4 (API 15)

[image]
[image]
[image]

**HTC Desire A9191**, Android 2.3.5 (API 10)

[image]

**DDMS**

[image]

**EDITED**

activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            />
</DrawerLayout>
```

fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <!-- other views here -->

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/consumer_profile_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean? how to avoid this?

Comment: Sry for OT, but are u from nuremberg?

Comment: Could you show your XML Layout?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So, I find workaround solution: just wrap `MapView` into container and place empty `View` above. Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16231935/1891118

There is my updated layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it also helped me with a similar case but I'm using a VideoView instead of a MapView.

Comment: Also works with `ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView`. A simple and elegant solution!

Comment: Also fixes the same problem with com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView. Thanks