# Android GoogleMap overlaps Views onResume

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm displaying a `GoogleMap` in a `RelativeLayout`, with a `TextView` (among other things) over:

```
<RelativeLayout
    width=match_parent
    height=match_parent>
    <Map
        width=match_parent
        height=match_parent />
    <TextView
        with=100dp
        height=100dp />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For some reason, if I hit home, then reopen the app, the Map will be over (covering) the `TextView`.

I tried to use `SupportMapFragment`, and `MapView` (with `zOrderOnTop="false"`) but no effect.
I also tried to show / hide the Map in `onResume` / `onPause`, no effect.

I also had the [`Drawer` issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314383/android-mapview-overlaps-drawerlayout), but the suggested fix only solved the `Drawer` problem.

Versions:
`com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+`
`compileSdkVersion 19`
`minSdkVersion 14`
`targetSdkVersion 14`.

Note: this problem only occurs on Samsung Galaxy SII (4.0.4).
Any idea? Thanks.

Update: I also tried to inflate the `Fragment` from the code instead of XML, or use `GoogleMapOptions` to set `zOrderOnTop(false)`, still same result...

Update 2: I think I narrowed down the problem:

Working:

drawer.xml

```
<Drawer>
    <RelativeLayout
        width=match_parent
        height=match_parent>
        <RelativeLayout
            width=match_parent
            height=match_parent>
            <Map
                width=match_parent
                height=match_parent>
            <View
                width=match_parent
                height=match_parent
                background=transparent>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            width=100dp
            height=100dp>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView /> <!-- menu -->
</Drawer>
```

Not working:

drawer.xml

```
<Drawer>
    <FrameLayout /> <!-- fragment container -->

    <ListView /> <!-- menu -->
</Drawer>
```

map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    width=match_parent
    height=match_parent>
    <RelativeLayout
        width=match_parent
        height=match_parent>
        <Map
            width=match_parent
            height=match_parent>
        <View
            width=match_parent
            height=match_parent
            background=transparent>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        width=100dp
        height=100dp>
</RelativeLayout>
```

One solution would be to have the Map declared in drawer.xml, then use `setVisibility` to show / hide it when needed... Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <!-- Extra hack ViewGroup to fix Map z-ordering -->
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Map
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <View 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        with=100dp
        height=100dp />

</RelativeLayout>
```

At least for me, this was sufficient to fix issues with the z-order. I believe this issue only effects pre Jellybean devices, which explains why you are seeing it on your SII.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. It only fixes the drawer issue, not the main problem...