# Activities MapView overlapping fragments layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have been scratching my head on an issue related to Google MapView where a MapView embedded in an activity is overlapping or staying in the foreground over a fragment that also hosts a SupportMapFragment.

Below is the **activity.xml** file source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/loginbg">

    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar" android:id="@+id/tbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tbar">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The **fragment_container** above is the container where I am loading a fragment that hosts a SupportMapFragment.

Below is the layout of the **fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimaryDarkNew"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </FrameLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            style="@style/BlueButton"
            android:text="Continue"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the app, its showing up as below where top half part of the fragment is getting overlapped by the hosting activities MapView. However one thing I noticed is that the top right button which is part of the fragment is showing up correctly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkDry.png

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Below is the maps library version I am using

*compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'*

Comment: can you change the fragment_container to the outer layout?

Comment: Thank you lal for taking interest in the question, I have tried moving the fragment_container in the outer layout. However, the result is just the same.

Comment: Why are you displaying 2 mapviews on the same screen? If you have a mapview in the main layout then why is fragment_container also holding it? Your layout looks complicated. Can you tell what are you trying to make? What output you want?

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari I am trying to have two screens in the app, the first will be a big map where I can add a marker  and a second screen that will show a half screen map with the marker selected on first screen... I am not intending to display two maps one below other but two screens, one with full map and another with 50% of screen.

Comment: Move the 2nd FrameLayout outside the 1st one and let me know the result. Also, what is this for?? '<View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>'

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari I have already tried that as already suggested, same result. "<View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"/>" is for making the child layouts of equal height

Comment: Have tried a solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314383/android-mapview-overlaps-drawerlayout), however could not get it to work... The same issue persists